# PXE and Memory hole

Tags: pxe

I want to boot a board with PXE. When it tries to download kernel from TFTP server, it fails with an error:

```
Not enough memory to load specified image
```

After investigation, I came to know that underlying board have a memory hole at approximately 8MB, Due to which I can not load kernel/initrd of larger size.

If I have to boot normally on such board, `grub` helps me with an option `uppermem`, which bypassed memory hole.

SYSLINUX documents `linux.c32` for this purpose. But didn't find a way to use it. How to use it ?

OR Is there any such option, as `uppermem`, available for TFTP/PXE ?

Comment: Have your BIOS 'Memory Hole Remmaping' settings parameter?

Comment: That was my first hit. But underlying BIOS do not have any setting related to Memory Hole

Comment: Is your kernel image compressed?

Comment: Yes. It's compressed image, having size of 15mb+. It's 4.16 kernel

Comment: I haven't been found options like `uppermem` for SYSLINUX too. I would suggest to you to boot via GRUB (legacy, not GRUB 2) in PXE. GRUB2 doesn't implement `uppermem` option.

Comment: How to boot using grub via proxy ?

Comment: Try to google first, as booting via PXE is not rocket science, even though used infrequently for Linux. Ex: http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/iainr/documentation/pdf/pxe.pdf And forget about memory hole remapping, that concept is long obsolete. It's from the old ISA and PCI mobos of the late 90s and WinXP 32bit kind of ages.